# Can I link an existing .so to another .so so that ldd will show their association?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I have two existing .so files:

- a.so
- b.so

ldd reports that neither of them know about the other, but `a.so` depends on a function in `b.so` in this contrived example:

```
# ldd -r a.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe8e7bb000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3d8830c000)
undefined symbol: b_test_func   (./a.so)

# ldd -r b.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe8e7bb000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3d8830c000)

# objdump -T b.so
0000000000fac7a0 g    DF .text  0000000000000f80 b_test_func
```

Since `a.so` was not compiled against `b.so`, the linker has left the symbol `b_test_func` unresolved such that `ldd` does not list `b.so` as a dependency, otherwise you would see something like `b.so => /foo/b.so` in the `ldd a.so` output.

I need to dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM) `a.so` into a new namespace, hence `a.so` must depend on `b.so` since RTLD_GLOBAL is not supported by dlmopen() because of [this bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18684).  (Note that dlopen(RTLD_GLOBAL) does work).

Therefore we need the glibc dynamic linker to resolve the linkage itself by making `a.so` indicate that it needs `b.so` so they can operate in the same namespace and dlmopen() will resolve the dependency automatically.  Without the link shown by `ldd` they won't use eachothers' shared symbols so dlsym() will fail to resolve.

Questions:

- Is there a way to modify `a.so` so that `ldd a.so` will try to resolve `b.so` ?
- What is this linkage shown by `ldd` known as so I can refer to it properly?

Comment: How about this sequence: `bhandle= dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM,"b"); dlinfo(bhandle,RTLD_DI_LMID,&lmid); ahandle= dlmopen(lmid, "a");` Or perhaps you can create a _loader.so_ that depends both on "a" and "b" so you only have to dlopen this loader.so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to modify a.so so that ldd a.so will try to resolve b.so ?

On most UNIX systems, `.so` is the *final* link product, and no further modification is possible.

You may be able to use `patchelf --add-needed b.so a.so`, but simply `dlmopen`ing `b.so` *before* you `dlmopen` `a.so` (as suggested by Lorinczy Zsigmond) is probably an easier solution.